# Have a Button to add same component in React

Tags: redux, react-redux, reactjs

I am trying to implement a add button, clicking on which will render a component. Now that component fetches data once it mounts(call is made in `componentDidMount()`). In my implementation, even if i add a new component, even the old one gets mounted again which is not what i want.

This is my component

```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state = {
                panels = []
            }
        }

        handleClick(event){
             const initialState = this.state.panels;
             this.setState({
                  panels: initialState.concat(<Panel key={initialState.length} />)
             )}
        }
        render(){
            return(
                 <div>
                 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add new</button>
                 {this.state.panels}
                 </div>
            )
        }
     }
```

Now, what happens is, whenever i add a new component, even the old one is mounted again and it starts fetching data that it already has fetched. How do I correct this? How do i dynamically add new components without bothering previously dynamically added components to the DOM without using `ReactDOM.render()` ?

Comment: Can you put your data fetching logic inside the constructor function of Panel class?

Comment: What data are you trying to fetch?If that is something generic, why can't you fetch that data in the parent component itself?

Comment: I can definitely do that @VivekN I am going to have further buttons in Panel container which will fetch different data, but if this problem persists, previously mounted Panel will fetch default data again

Answer (score 1):

Don't store Component instances on your internal state, store the data you need to render it. With React is top-down, data to UI flow.

Let's suppose your Panel needs an id which for the sake of simplicity will be the index in the array. Change your code to the following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state = {
                panels = []
            }
        }

        handleClick(event){
             const nextId = this.state.panels.length + 1
             this.setState({
                  panels: this.state.panels.concat([nextId])
             })
        }
        render(){
            return(
               <div>
                 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add new</button>
                 <div className='panel-wrapper'>
                  {
                    this.state.panels.map((panelId) => (
                      <Panel key={panelId} id={panelId} />
                    )
                  }
                  </div>
                 </div>
            )
        }
     }
```

By setting a key React will know which one is new and which already was there in the previous render. This is the React way, you update your data, and let your render function use that data at any given moment to represent your UI.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this is a better approach, but will this also not lead to componentDidMount firing for the previously created Panel component?

Comment: Nope, because it's mounted the first time React finds a new "key". That's why the `key` prop is useful! Try it, it should work like a charm. ;) You could even make each of those Panels be a container itself, if you're into Redux or similar.

Comment: Hi @CharlieBrown, i tried your approach but the previously mounted components get mounted again leading to the fetching. I had previously also set different keys for different Panels. Didn't work

Comment: Yup @CharlieBrown, Panel is a container and i am dispatching an actionCreator on componentDidMount() but that is not my headache at all. This one is.

Comment: Without seeing Panel there's not much we can do :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do it in non-react way. React way is to have render method that will display as many components, as described by state, be it 0,1,2... Then you add button will add one more element to state, and render will display all of them, and you do not need to worry about mounting components, and similar.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. When render will display all of them, it re-renders previously rendered component as well.

Comment: Your problem is very likely that you bind data fetching with rendering (or mounting). When you click button, you should start fetch, modify state for new control to be "fetching", when data arrives, modify state for new control again to contain  received data. Your view will nicely refresh for all of those state changes, and fetch would be issued only once (when you clicked the button).

Comment: One thing that takes time to get used to is that any change to user interface you would like to accomplish, you have to accomplish by changing the state.

Comment: Another thing, is that learning react alone is actually harder than learning react+redux combination